# How to check whether a particular field in SQL has values or not

Tags: sql-server

I've a table as below, if the Date has null then I want to get the WorkType

[image]

```
Empid Role WorkType1 DATE1     WorkType2 DATE2     WorkType3 DATE3
8     P001 Work1     NULL      Work2     NULL      Work3     NULL   
9     P002 Work2     12/9/2016 Work6     NULL      Work3     NULL
2     P003 Work3     NULL      Work6     12/9/2016 Work2     2/9/2016
7     P004 Work4     NULL      Work6     12/9/2016 Work5     NULL   
1     P005 Work5     12/9/2016 Work4     NULL      Work3     NULL
2     P006 Work6     NULL      Work1     12/9/2016 Work5     NULL
```

Comment: does it returns null or empty?

Comment: Just use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`. If a field contains an empty string it *does* have a value. If you want to check for null or empty string, use `myField is null or myfield =''`

Comment: 'null' means 'unknown' in sql. You can give empty or whitespace whatever meaning you want

Answer (score 1):

Easiet but not best solution would be to simply count nulls in each column then you can use this a subquery and count total sum.

```
    select sum(case when work1_date is null then 1 else 0 end) as count_nulls_workdate1, 
           sum(case when work2_date is null then 1 else 0 end) as count_nulls_workdate2,
           sum(case when work3_date is null then 1 else 0 end) as count_nulls_workdate3 
      from empno;
```

Comment: I've a table as below, if the Date has null then I want to get the WorkType

ID EMPLOYE Role WorkType1 DATE1 WorkType2 DATE2 WorkType3 DATE3 WorkType4 DATE4
8946790 P001 R1 Work1 NULL Work2 NULL Work3 NULL Work4 NULL
8921042 P002 R2 Work2 12/9/2016 10:05 Work6 NULL Work3 NULL Work1 12/9/2016 10:05
9329242 P003 R3 Work3 NULL Work6 12/9/2016 10:05 Work2 12/9/2016 10:05 Work5 NULL
8513795 P004 R6 Work4 NULL Work6 12/9/2016 10:05 Work5 NULL Work1 12/9/2016 10:05
1 P005 R2 Work5 12/9/2016 10:05 Work4 NULL Work3 NULL Work2 NULL
2 P006 R1 Work6 NULL Work1 12/9/2016 10:05 Work5 NULL Work3 NULL

Comment: You should either edit your original question or post it as a new question. Comments aren't great for posting blocks of data like that.

Comment: I've a table as below, if the Date has null then I want to get the WorkType

Empid Role WorkType1 DATE1 WorkType2 DATE2 WorkType3 DATE3
8         P001 Work1         NULL   Work2         NULL   Work3         NULL 9         P002 Work2       12/9/2016 Work6      NULL   Work3         NULL
2         P003 Work3        NULL     Work6      12/9/2016 Work2 12/9/2016
7         P004 Work4       NULL     Work6      12/9/2016 Work5 NULL 
1         P005 Work5      12/9/2016 Work4       NULL      Work3        NULL
2    P006 Work6        NULL      Work1     12/9/2016 Work5 NULL

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select count(*)-count(work1_date) as count_nulls_workdate1, 
       count(*)-count(work2_date) as count_nulls_workdate2,
       count(*)-count(work3_date) as count_nulls_workdate3 
      from Table;
```

count does not count null values, so count(*), which counts records - count(field) = count of nulls

Answer (score 0):

The answer below is my interpretation of your requirements, your question is a little unclear.

```
SELECT
ID,
EMPLOYEE,
[ROLE],
WorkType1,
    CASE WHEN Date1 IS NULL THEN WorkType1 ELSE CAST(Date1 AS VARCHAR(23)) END Date1,
WorkType2,
    CASE WHEN Date2 IS NULL THEN WorkType2 ELSE CAST(Date2 AS VARCHAR(23)) END Date2,
WorkType3,
    CASE WHEN Date3 IS NULL THEN WorkType3 ELSE CAST(Date3 AS VARCHAR(23)) END Date3
WorkType4,
    CASE WHEN Date4 IS NULL THEN WorkType4 ELSE CAST(Date4 AS VARCHAR(23)) END Date4
```

The explicit conversion of Date to Varchar(23) is required as you are mixing Worktype with Date values which are not compatible data types *I chose varchar(23) to allow for datetime*

Depending on your DB settings you may need to additionally split your dates to retain the format you desire in your output the below gives yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.

```
CAST(Datepart(Year,Date1) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-'+ RIGHT('00'+CAST(Datepart(Month,Date1) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(Datepart(Day,Date1) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ' ' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(Datepart(HH,Date1) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)+ ':' + RIGHT('00'+CAST(Datepart(MINUTE,Date1) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':' + RIGHT('00'+CAST(Datepart(ss,Date) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
```

I used the following to test

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATEtime = '2017-01-01', @Date2 DATEtime = NULL, @Date3 Datetime = '2017-01-02'
,@Worktype1 Varchar(20) = 'Test1'
,@Worktype2 Varchar(20) = 'Test2'
,@Worktype3 Varchar(20) = 'Test3'

SELECT
    CASE WHEN @Date1 IS NULL THEN @WorkType1 ELSE CAST(@Date1 AS VARCHAR(25)) END Date1, /*Varchar 23 date*/
    CASE WHEN @Date2 IS NULL THEN @WorkType2 ELSE CAST(@Date2 AS VARCHAR(25)) END Date2, /* Result of Worktype2 due to null */
    CASE WHEN @Date3 IS NULL THEN @WorkType3 ELSE CAST(Datepart(Year,@Date3) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-'+ RIGHT('00'+CAST(Datepart(Month,@Date3) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(Datepart(Day,@Date3) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ' ' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(Datepart(HH,@Date3) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)+ ':' + RIGHT('00'+CAST(Datepart(MINUTE,@Date3) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':' + RIGHT('00'+CAST(Datepart(ss,@Date3) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) END Date3 /* Result for Date 3 formatted to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss*/
```

which provides the following result set

[ResultSet][1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1uUp.jpg